# Rails factory girl create with multiple models(sti)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have factory `Rule` which is parent for my other factories

parent is regular model

```
 class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fee
end

class Fee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rules
end

 FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :rule do
    type { rule_classes.sample }
    name { SecureRandom.hex }
    data '["name"]'
    association :fee, factory: :fee
  end
```

my children rule models looks like `AirlineRule < Rule`

```
  factory :airlines_rule, parent: :rule, class: 'AirlinesRule' do
    data "airlines": ["KL","PN"]
  end
```

but now i want to create `Fee's` factory `fee_with_all_rules` is it possible?

i have tried

```
factory :fee_with_all_rules do
  association :fee, factory: [:airlines_rule, :connections_rule]
end
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

you can use `after(:build)`

```
after(:build) { |fee| FactoryGirl.build(:airlines_rule, fee: fee) }
```

try something like this